# Existence of a simple closed curve which is not null-homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Problem.** *Assume that $U$ is an open and connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$, and $\gamma :[0,1]\to U$ is a closed curve, which is not null-homotopic in $U$ and not necessarily simple closed. Show that there exists a simple closed curve, which is not null-homotopic in $U$.*

I am sure that this is a standard problem, and I am looking for an elegant, if possible, solution or a reference. I have in mind the following sketch of proof:

a. Construct a polygonal closed curve $\tilde\gamma$ which is homotopic with $\gamma$ in $U$.

b. Construct $\tilde\gamma$ so that it intersects itself in finitely many points, and not whole segments.

c. Use induction on the number of self–intersections of $\tilde\gamma$, in order to show that $\tilde\gamma$ is written as a product (in the fundamental group's sense) of simple closed polygonal curves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to U$ be the (a) universal covering. We know that the covering space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the uniformisation theorem.

Let $\hat{\gamma} \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a lift of $\gamma$. Since $\gamma$ is not null-homotopic, we have $\hat{\gamma}(1) \neq \hat{\gamma}(0)$. Define $\beta$ as the straight line segment connecting these points, $\beta(t) = (1-t)\hat{\gamma}(0) + t\hat{\gamma}(1)$. Next define

$$s = \inf \bigl\{ t \in (0,1] : \bigl(\exists u \in [0,t)\bigr)\bigl(\pi(\beta(t)) = \pi(\beta(u))\bigr)\bigr\}.$$

We claim that there is an $u \in [0,s)$ with $\pi(\beta(s)) = \pi(\beta(u))$: Choose a neighbourhood $V$ of $\beta(s)$ on which $\pi$ is injective. There is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\beta(t) \in V$ for all $t \in [s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon]$. We have sequences $t_n$ and $u_n$ with $\pi(\beta(t_n)) = \pi(\beta(u_n))$ where $t_n \geqslant t_{n+1} \geqslant s$ and $u_n < t_n$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $t_n < s + \varepsilon$ for all $n$. Since $\pi$ is injective on $V$, we have $u_n < s - \varepsilon$ for all $n$. After taking a subsequence, we can assume that $u_n$ converges to some $u \leqslant s - \varepsilon$. By continuity,

$$\pi(\beta(s)) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \pi(\beta(t_n)) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \pi(\beta(u_n)) = \pi(\beta(u)).$$

Now define $\tilde{\beta}(t) = \beta((1-t)u + ts)$ and $\tilde{\gamma} = \pi \circ \tilde{\beta}$. By construction, $\tilde{\gamma}$ is a simple closed curve in $U$, and since $\beta(u) \neq \beta(s)$, it is not null-homotopic.

Comment: Could you please give a reference for the uniformisation theorem you are using ? Thanks

Comment: @user90041 The [uniformisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) of complex analysis. We can identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and thus endow $U$ with the structure of a Riemann surface. Using that, we can endow the universal covering space with the structure of a Riemann surface. Since the universal cover is simply connected, it is either the unit disk, the plane, or the Riemann sphere, up to biholomorphic equivalence. It cannot be the sphere, since $U$ is not compact, hence it's the disk or the plane. Topologically, both are the same.

Comment: Of course I expect there is also a topological classification of simply connected surfaces, but I'm more familiar with complex analysis, so I use that.

Comment: @DanielFischer See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of D. Fischer is very elegant and of course correct. I am providing a modification of a part of his answer which:

a. Avoids the use of the Uniformisation Theorem of Riemann Surfaces, and

b. It applies even in the case $U$ is a topological manifold of any dimension.

Assume that $U$ is a connected but topological manifold, which is not simply connected, and hence there exists a non null-homotopic closed curve $\gamma: [0,1]\to U$. Let $X$ be the universal covering space of $U$, and $\pi: X\to U$ the corresponding covering map. (Such $X$ and $\pi$ do exist, as $U$ is a connected manifold.) Let $\tilde\gamma :[0,1]\to X$ be a lifting of $\gamma$, i.e., $\pi\circ\tilde\gamma=\gamma$. We shall show that there exists a curve $\hat\gamma : [0,1]\to X$, homotopic to $\tilde\gamma$, which is injective. Once we achieve that, the rest is obtained by D. Fischer's proof.

In fact, it suffices to show the following:

**Fact.** *If $X$ is a connected topological manifold, and $x,y\in X$, $x\ne y$, then there exists an injective curve $\gamma : [0,1]\to X$, connecting $x$ and $y$.*

*Proof of the Fact.* Fix $x_0\in X$. It suffices to show that the set
$$
W=\{x\in X: x\ne x_0\,\,\,\text{and $x_0$ is connected to $x$ by an injective curve}\}\cup\{x_0\},
$$
is both open and closed.

a. $W$ is open: Let $x_1\in W$, and $V$ an open neighbourhood of $x_1$ which is homeomorphic to the unit ball $B_1(0)$, with $p: V\to B_1(0)$ a homeomorphism, $p(x_1)=0$, and $x_2\in V$. If $x_2$ belongs to the curve $\gamma : [0,1]\to X$, which connects $x_0$ and $x_1$ we are done. Assume that $x_2$ does not belong to the curve, and let $r=\|p(x_2)\|<1$.  Let
$$
d=\mathrm{dist}\big(p(x_2),\overline{B}(0,r)\cap p(\gamma[I])\big)>0.
$$
Let $y_3\in \overline{B}(0,r)$, such that $\|y_3-p(x_2)\|=d$, (such $y_3$ exists since $\overline{B}(0,r)\cap p(\gamma[I])$ is compact)
and $J$ the segment connecting $y_3$ and $p(x_2)$. Then the union of $p^{-1}(J)$ and the part of $\gamma$ which connects $x_0$ with $x_2$ is an injective curve connecting $x_0$ and $x_1$.

b. $W$ is closed: Using a similar approach to the one we just used, it is readily obtained that a limit point of $W$ also belong to $W$.

Comment: Nice. I shouldn't have been so lazy ;)